# Python telegram InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно использовать inlineButton, вроде делал по примеру, но все равно не работает. Получаю ошибку

```
2017-05-28 17:47:48,933 (__init__.py:250 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID"}']"
```

Функция parse.get_events возвращает список чемпионатов вида:

```
['Пляжный футбол', 'Пляжный футбол. Кубок Европейских Чемпионов', 'Футбол. Германия. Оберлига']
```

Из каждого хочу сделать кнопку

```
import sqlite3
from telebot import types
import parse

bot = telebot.TeleBot(constants.token)

def pages_keyboard(m):
    """Формируем Inline-кнопки для перехода по страницам.
    """
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btns = []
    for i in m:
        btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=i, callback_data=i))
    keyboard.add(*btns)
    return keyboard # возвращаем объект клавиатуры

@bot.message_handler(func = lambda message: 'Футбол' in message.text)
def handler_soccer(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбирай', parse_mode = 'Markdown', reply_markup = pages_keyboard(parse.get_events('Футбол')))
```

Comment: `callback_data` возможно должно быть без пробелов и других спецсимволов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ простой - у параметра `callback_data` есть *ограничение по весу*.
Очевидно, что вторая и третья кнопка в Вашей **Inline-клавиатуре** весят больше допустимого (поэтому сервера **Telegram** и ругаются).
Сократите кол-во символов, принимаемых в переменную `callback_data`.
Проверьте работоспособность кода изменив на следующее:

```
btns.append(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=i, callback_data=i[0:-10]))
```

Comment: UPD: сверился с Telegram Bot API. callback_data может хранить в себе адрес на объект весом 1-64 bytes.

Comment: UPD #2: через sys.getsizeof() проверил максимальный размер, на который сервер не ругается. Вопреки документации максимальный размер составляет 132 bytes.

Comment: добавляйте обновления через правку ответа, а не в комментарии.